# Fastest way to lowercase a numpy array of unicode strings in Cython

Tags: python, numpy, unicode, cython

Numpy's string functions are all very slow and are less performant than pure python lists. I am looking to optimize all the normal string functions using Cython.

For instance, let's take a numpy array of 100,000 unicode strings with data type either unicode or object and lowecase each one.

```
alist = ['JsDated', 'УКРАЇНА'] * 50000
arr_unicode = np.array(alist)
arr_object = np.array(alist, dtype='object')

%timeit np.char.lower(arr_unicode)
51.6 ms ± 1.99 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Using a list comprehension is just as fast

```
%timeit [a.lower() for a in arr_unicode]
44.7 ms ± 2.69 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

For the object data type, we cannot use `np.char`. The list comprehension is 3x as fast.

```
%timeit [a.lower() for a in arr_object]
16.1 ms ± 147 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

The only way I know how to do this in Cython is to create an empty object array and call the Python string method `lower` on each iteration.

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from numpy cimport ndarray

def lower(ndarray[object] arr):
    cdef int i
    cdef int n = len(arr)
    cdef ndarray[object] result = np.empty(n, dtype='object')
    for i in range(n):
        result[i] = arr[i].lower()
    return result
```

This yields a modest improvement

```
%timeit lower(arr_object)
11.3 ms ± 383 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

I have tried accessing the memory directly with the `data` ndarray attribute like this:

```
def lower_fast(ndarray[object] arr):
    cdef int n = len(arr)
    cdef int i
    cdef char* data = arr.data
    cdef int itemsize = arr.itemsize
    for i in range(n):
        # no idea here
```

I believe `data` is one contiguous piece of memory holding all the raw bytes one after the other. Accessing these bytes is extremely fast and it seems converting these raw bytes would increase performance by 2 orders of magnitude. I found a [`tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/tolower) c++ function that might work, but I don't know how to hook it in with Cython.

#### Update with fastest method (doesn't work for unicode)

Here is the fastest method I found by far, from another SO post. This lowercases all the ascii characters by accessing the numpy memoryview via the `data` attribute. I think it will mangle other unicode characters that have bytes between 65 and 90 as well. But the speed is very good.

```
cdef int f(char *a, int itemsize, int shape):
    cdef int i
    cdef int num
    cdef int loc
    for i in range(shape * itemsize):
        num = a[i]
        print(num)
        if 65 <= num <= 90:
            a[i] +=32

def lower_fast(ndarray arr):
    cdef char *inp
    inp = arr.data
    f(inp, arr.itemsize, arr.shape[0])
    return arr
```

This is 100x faster than the others and what I am looking for.

```
%timeit lower_fast(arr)
103 µs ± 1.23 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: What's `arr`? You defined `alist`, `arr_unicode`, and `arr_object`, but then referred to some unknown `arr`.

Comment: (Note that the `np.char` functions just build Python strings, call the corresponding Python string methods, and convert the results back to a NumPy array.)

Comment: @user2357112 Good catch. It was meant to be `arr_unicode` which won't change anything

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, that makes sense on what is happening, but numpy has no other builtin ways for doing string operations correct? i.e., `np.char.lower` is the fastest way of doing this in NumPy, correct?

Comment: I tried a `pandas.DataSeries` and got an improvement, but the list comprehension is still faster.

Comment: @Craig Pandas and numpy are useless here, which is why I want to do this in Cython. I was able to lowercase ascii strings extremely fast by incrementing the bytes by 32 but this won't work for unicode strings.

Comment: @TedPetrou - which is why I offered that as a comment and not an answer--to document that the operations in pandas are faster than numpy, but they don't achieve the *unstated* speedup you require.

Comment: Trying to use `tolower` for Unicode is going to be tricky, since wchar_t is compiler-dependent and not very portable.

Comment: @TedPetrou Is `np.char.lower(arr_unicode)` doing the intended to-lower conversion? To me it seems its just changing the uppercase letters to lower ones.

Comment: @Divakar Yes, `np.char.lower` is working correctly for all unicode characters.

Comment: @Divakar, you can test it with this unicode text: `arr = np.array(['УКРАЇНА'], dtype=np.unicode_)`. Correct result should be: `array(['україна'], dtype='<U7')`

Comment: Thanks @MaxU. That's a much better string for testing.

Comment: Hmm, I think I got the point. Thanks guys. Appreciate the feedback!

Comment: Iteration on an object array takes about the same time as iteration on a list.  In effect both are working with pointers to the strings.  `np.char` is doing the slower iteration on a character array.

Comment: (Also, consider that Unicode case mappings aren't all 1 character to 1 character. For example, `'ß'.upper() == 'SS'`. `str.upper` handles this fine, but `np.char.upper` doesn't realize the result needs more room.)

Comment: Just an idea - what about checking the `str.lower()` implementation for Python 3.x in source files?

Comment: @user2357112 Very interesting, had no idea about that.

Comment: @MaxU Thanks for the suggestion. I looked at the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L9872) for a few minutes but only see rabbit holes :)

Comment: @user2357112: on your specific example: the capital eszet `ẞ` has been included in Unicode in 2008. Is Python's Unicode implementation slow to catch up?

Comment: @TedPetrou, i'm not sure whether it helps, but you could take a look at [this function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/unicodectype.c#L211)

Comment: @usr2564301: I believe the capital Eszett was nonstandard in German orthography until [very recently](https://qz.com/1033265/germanys-century-long-debate-over-a-missing-letter-in-its-alphabet/). Standard practice was to use SS. While Unicode has encoded the capital Eszett since 5.1, the Unicode standard still specifies SS as the capital of ß. See the [Unicode FAQ](http://unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html#11) (although that entry might currently be a bit out of date).

Answer (score 1):

This was only slightly faster than the list comprehension for me on my machine, but if you want unicode support this might be the fastest way of doing it. You'll need to `apt-get install libunistring-dev` or whatever is appropriate for your OS / package manager.

In some C file, say, `_lower.c`, have

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>   
#include <unistr.h>
#include <unicase.h>

void _c_tolower(uint8_t  **s, uint32_t total_len) {
    size_t lower_len, s_len;
    uint8_t *s_ptr = *s, *lowered;
    while(s_ptr - *s < total_len) {
        s_len = u8_strlen(s_ptr);
        if (s_len == 0) {
            s_ptr += 1;
            continue;
        }
        lowered = u8_tolower(s_ptr, s_len, NULL, NULL, NULL, &lower_len);
        memcpy(s_ptr, lowered, lower_len);
        free(lowered);
        s_ptr += s_len;
    }
}
```

Then, in `lower.pxd` you do

```
cdef extern from "_lower.c":
    cdef void _c_tolower(unsigned char **s, unsigned int total_len)
```

And finally, in `lower.pyx`:

```
cpdef void lower(ndarray arr):
    cdef unsigned char * _arr
    _arr = <unsigned char *> arr.data
    _c_tolower(&_arr, arr.shape[0] * arr.itemsize)
```

On my laptop, I got 46ms for the list comprehension you had above and 37ms for this method (and 0.8ms for your `lower_fast`), so it's probably not worth it, but I figured I'd type it out in case you wanted an example of how to hook such a thing into Cython.

There are a few points of improvement that I don't know will make much of a difference:

- `arr.data` is something like a square matrix I guess? (I don't know, I don't use numpy for anything), and pads the ends of the shorter strings with `\x00`s. I was too lazy to figure out how to get `u8_tolower` to look past the 0s, so I just manually fast-forward past them (that's what the `if (s_len == 0)` clause is doing). I suspect that one call to `u8_tolower` would be significantly faster than doing it thousands of times.
- I'm doing a lot of freeing/memcpying. You can probably avoid that if you're clever.
- I *think* it's the case that every lowercase unicode character is at most as wide as its uppercase variant, so this should not run into any segfaults or buffer overwrites or just overlapping substring issues, but don't take my word for that.

Not really an answer, but hope it helps your further investigations!

PS You'll notice that this does the lowering in-place, so the usage would be like this:

```
>>> alist = ['JsDated', 'УКРАЇНА', '道德經', 'Ну И йЕшШо'] * 2
>>> arr_unicode = np.array(alist)
>>> lower_2(arr_unicode)
>>> for x in arr_unicode:
...     print x
...
jsdated
україна
道德經
ну и йешшо
jsdated
україна
道德經
ну и йешшо

>>> alist = ['JsDated', 'УКРАЇНА'] * 50000
>>> arr_unicode = np.array(alist)
>>> ct = time(); x = [a.lower() for a in arr_unicode]; time() - ct;
0.046072959899902344
>>> arr_unicode = np.array(alist)
>>> ct = time(); lower_2(arr_unicode); time() - ct
0.037489891052246094
```

EDIT

DUH, you modify the C function to look like this

```
void _c_tolower(uint8_t  **s, uint32_t total_len) {
    size_t lower_len;
    uint8_t *lowered;

    lowered = u8_tolower(*s, total_len, NULL, NULL, NULL, &lower_len);
    memcpy(*s, lowered, lower_len);
    free(lowered);
}
```

and then it does it all in one go. Looks more dangerous in terms of possibly having something from the old data left over of `lower_len` is shorter than the original string... in short, this code is TOTALLY EXPERIMENTAL AND FOR ILLUSTRATIVE PURPOSES ONLY DO NOT USE THIS IN PRODUCTION IT WILL PROBABLY BREAK.

Anyway, ~40% faster this way:

```
>>> alist = ['JsDated', 'УКРАЇНА'] * 50000
>>> arr_unicode = np.array(alist)
>>> ct = time(); lower_2(arr_unicode); time() - ct
0.022463043975830078
```

Comment: Why pass `&arr` and not just `arr`? You never assign `*s =`, so I see no reason to.

Comment: Also, this fails on non-contiguous arrays like `arr_unicode[::2]`

Comment: @Eric you're right -- it was from a first version of the function I tried before using memcpy. 

And, definitely. I mostly wrote it up because OP said he's not sure how to hook his C++ function into python, so it's mostly illustrative.

Comment: Thanks very much for putting this all together. I think a more straightforward approach would be to not do the operation in place and simply pass each individual string to `to_lower` in a for loop and simply return the new string. This would avoid any memory copying.

Comment: Yes, but then a) your new string will not be wrapped in a numpy.ndarray object, and b) if you are not careful you will have a potential memory leak. 

It would also be slower to do that one string at a time, because each string would be converted from a python unicode object to an `unsigned char *` and then back. When possible, send as little data as possible, as few times as possible, through the python-C barrier.